# min, max functions in sass SassError: Internal Error: Incompatible units:

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to do use the functions `min` and `max` in sass. with two values of different type,

`width: max(55vw, 650px);`

And it gives me the error

`SassError: Internal Error: Incompatible units: 'vw' and 'px'`

This function works well in plain css, but doesn't work in sass. does this mean sass has limited functionalities than css or am I missing something? since comparing `%` and `vw` values with pixels is the most widely used way for functions like min and max.

How can I make this work in sass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `width: calc(max(55vw, 650px));`

For reference visit closed query about the same on **github node-sass issue:**

https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2815

Answer (score 1):

The main problem of sass when writing some functions is the incompatibility with the min and max functions, which is solved by writing min with capital letters.
As for the incompatibility to work with data of different measures, such as px and% then the problem is quite simple just enter the number en px in this way:
`(#{1200px})`

These advanced function examples can clarify the syntax a bit if you have to use:
Your example:

OBJETIVE (CSS):
`width: max (55vw, 650px);`

WORKING SASS:
`width: Min ((# {55vw}), 650px);`

SASS COMPILED EN CSS:
`width: Max (55vw, 650px);`